# How stop string.Contains() picking out a word that is within another word. Better explanation below

Tags: c#, string, contains

I am using speech recognition in my program and to make it easier than writing out every possible combination of words to execute a certain command, I am using the .Contains function to pick out certain keywords. Example...

```
private void SpeechHypothesized(object sender, SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs e)
{
    string speech = e.Result.Text;

    if (speech.Contains("next") && speech.Contains("date"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(speech + "\nThe date will be the 11th");
    }
    else if (speech.Contains("date"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(speech + "\nThe date is the 10th");
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the speech is somewhat recognized, it will display a text box saying what it hypothesized and then the date. However, when I look at the speech that is displayed in the text box, it will say things like "next update". So, the program is looking for one word within another i.e. "date" inside of "update". I do not want this to happen otherwise it won't be as accurate, how can make the .Contains method pick out the word on it's own, and not look inside other words? Thanks

Comment: What does the string `speech` look like? Does it have spaces? If so, you can split on the space and search the resulting array for the word you want.

Comment: You need to use a regex for specificity like this.

Comment: `var speech = e.Result.Text.Split(' ');` and you won't have to change anything else

Comment: @alykins: While regular expressions can be a powerful tool in skilled hands, you never _need_ to use them :)

Comment: Good point... A Regex will make this sooooo much nicer; especially if OP is going to be doing a lot of looking up of words that could be in other words (be, at, an, a, I, it, is, in, etc). But yes, considering they have not been around forever, "need" is a little string lol

Comment: @alykins What is it about using a Regex that is "nicer" in your opinion? Genuine question lol it looks so sloppy to me and seems like overkill

Comment: @eddie_cat idk- I guess I'm more partial to regex'ing than the split- hadn't thought about doing it that way? I think it's pretty? lol

Comment: So if the input is "I want to date the next armadillo that walks into the bar." it will tell you the date you'll meet the 'dillo of your dreams? `<yoda>`Order matters not?`</yoda>`

Comment: If you don't want to split the string, you can just use `speech.Contains(" date ")`.  But RegEx might be more versatile for you needs.

Answer (score 6):

Alternative solution, split all the spaces and check for the keywords

```
string speech_text = e.Result.Text;
string[] speech = speech_text.Split();

if (speech.Contains("next") && speech.Contains("date"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(speech_text + "\nThe date will be the 11th");
}
else if (speech.Contains("date"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(speech_text + "\nThe date is the 10th");
}
```

Comment: IMO this is way simpler than using a Regex.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `String.Split` to get all words. Then use `Ènumerable.Contains` to check whether or not one of the words matches. Here is a sample which compares case-insensitively:

```
char[] wordSeparators = new[] { '\n', '\t', ',', '.', '!', '?', ';', ':', ' ', '-', '/', '\\', '[', ']', '(', ')', '<', '>', '@', '"', '\'' };
string[] words = e.Result.Text.Split(wordSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
bool containsNext = words.Contains("next", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
bool containsDate = words.Contains("date", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

if ( containsNext && containsDate )
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text + "\nThe date will be the 11th");
}
else if ( containsDate )
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text + "\nThe date is the 10th");
}
```

Could be convenient  as [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
static readonly char[] wordSeparators = { '\n', '\t', ',', '.', '!', '?', ';', ':', ' ', '-', '/', '\\', '[', ']', '(', ')', '<', '>', '@', '"', '\'' };

public static bool ContainsWord(this string input, string word, StringComparer comparer = null)
{
    if (input == null || word == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input and word must be specified");
    if (input.Length < word.Length) return false;
    if (comparer == null) comparer = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
    return input.Split(wordSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Contains(word, comparer);
}
```

Now you can use it everywhere in this way:

```
bool containsNext = e.Result.Text.ContainsWord("next");
bool containsDate = e.Result.Text.ContainsWord("date");
```

Answer (score 1):

With regular expressions you can force the word to be surrounded by ["word boundaries"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
private void SpeechHypothesized(object sender, SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs e)
{
    string speech = e.Result.Text;

    bool matchesDate = Regex.IsMatch(speech, @"\bdate\b");
    if (Regex.IsMatch(speech, @"\bnext\b") && matchesDate)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(speech + "\nThe date will be the 11th");
    }
    else if (matchesDate)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(speech + "\nThe date is the 10th");
    }
}
```

This will match for "next date" but not "next update".

Comment: Regex seems overqualified. `String.Split` will do the job nicely.

Comment: @PatriceGahide Splitting on space will miss `"date"` or `(date)` or other similar constructions, altough now that I think of it it probably won't happen in a speech recognition context!

Answer (score 0):

You are much better off using a regular expression.

```
        if (Regex.IsMatch(speech, @"\bnext\b") && Regex.IsMatch(speech, @"\bdate\b"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(speech + "\nThe date will be the 11th");
        }
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(speech, @"\bdate\b"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(speech + "\nThe date is the 10th");
        }
```